# pygame not found in Anaconda

Tags: python, pygame, anaconda, python-3.8, ubuntu-20.04

I'm trying to install pygame on an Ubuntu 20 machine (Python 3.8). Using `pip` gives a long list of dependency errors, so I used the recommended way of installing on Ubuntu, and ran:

`sudo apt-get install python3-pygame`

It ran through successfully, no errors But, trying to access the pygame module gives a ModuleNotFound error.

```
(base) ali@beast:~$ python3 -m pygame.examples.aliens
/home/ali/anaconda3/bin/python3: Error while finding module specification for 'pygame.examples.aliens' (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame')
```

I think this might be because I'm using Anaconda, and the installation done thru `apt get` is external to anaconda and isn't being pulled in by it.

Any ideas how to get Anaconda to recognize / pull in the external module?

Thanks.

P.S I setup python using anaconda, didn't use `apt` or any other way to install it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
pip install pygame==2.0.0.dev10
```

or better:

```
pip3 install pygame==2.0.0.dev10
```

References:

https://pypi.org/project/pygame/2.0.0.dev10/

Comment: UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found
to be incompatible with the existing python installation in your environment:

Specifications:

  - pygame -> python[version='2.7.*|3.5.*']

Your python: python=3.8

Comment: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with your CUDA driver:

  - feature:/linux-64::__cuda==10.2=0

Your installed CUDA driver is: 10.2

Comment: @ClickUpvote try both actually if one of them does not work.

Comment: How did you figure out the issue? Curious

Comment: this installization type is the only option for Python 3.8